# Initiating OAuth Integration From An Extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, oauth

Reading the [Magento guides](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html) only leaves a bit clueless how to easily to setup a OAuth access with an Extension.

The confusion is mostly is these 3 vague statements:

1. "You can register Integration through Magento Connect"
2. "Magento Connect generates a configuration file"
3. "you can manually create the configuration file and make it available to merchants"

I would like my extension to initiate the OAuth authentication process without having for the Administrator to manually add a new integration.  Preferably, using this "configuration file" (whatever that might be) and starting the OAuth "activate" process (from the Integrations section).

How is this possible?

Comment: Found this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/webapi/integration.html

Comment: And this https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/dev/tests/api-functional/_files/Magento/TestModuleIntegrationFromConfig

Comment: You got it working? I am looking for same thing.

Comment: @TejasShah No, sorry